# Path to lib/pythonX.Y/no-global-site-packages.txt

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

What is the official way to get the path of `lib/pythonX.Y/no-global-site-packages.txt`?

I would like to guess and use sys.version in a way which is finally slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source:

```
import site

site_mod_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(site.__file__))
no_global_file = os.path.join(site_mod_dir, 'no-global-site-packages.txt')
```